# can't get if statement with jquery cookie to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, cookies, if-statement

Ok so I am using this, https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie, jquery plugin and I need to do an `if (null){} else{}` but I can't get it to work

```
$('.ff').click(function(){
        if ($.cookie('ff') == null)
        {
            $.cookie('ff', 'on', { expires: 1, path: '/' });
            alert($.cookie('ff')+' on?');
        }
        if ($.cookie('ff') == 'on')
        {
            $.cookie('ff', null);
            alert($.cookie('ff')+' offFFFFFFFFFFFFFFff?');
        }
    });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your second `if` to an `else if`. Also, according to the plugin documentation:

> Note: when deleting a cookie, you must pass the exact same path, domain and secure options that were used to set the cookie.

So make sure to pass the same `path` option when you delete the cookie:

```
    if ($.cookie('ff') == null)
    {
        $.cookie('ff', 'on', { expires: 1, path: '/' });
        alert($.cookie('ff')+' on?');
    }
    else if ($.cookie('ff') == 'on')
    {
        $.cookie('ff', null, { path: '/' });
        alert($.cookie('ff')+' offFFFFFFFFFFFFFFff?');
    }
```

If `$.cookie('ff')` was null previously, it was first being set to `'on'` inside the first `if` block. Then the second condition was being evaluated to true, causing the cookie to be set to `null` again.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/azHK2/

Comment: that was my problem, not setting cookie empty the right way `$.cookie('ff', null, { path: '/' });`. Thank you